# How do i redirect a user to the previous page they came from after logging in? HTML/ASP

Tags: html, redirect, asp-classic

Hi i need to redirect my users to the same page they were just on after logging into my site, the redirectory code will obviously be a different page depending on the page tehy were last at, any help would be appreciate :)

Comment: Does the referer header tell you what page they were on?

Comment: I have a title of the page, but no referer header @Joe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Put an identifier for the page they are coming from in a hidden input in the form.
2. Copy it to the form you show on a "Login failed, try again" situation (if there is a failed login, otherwise go directly to 3).
3. Use that identifier to determine the URL to redirect to with a `Location:` header after a successful login

Comment: But how would i know which page i would have to redirect to because the page i came from will be different each time? Edit: i tried to use a Session but that didnt work.

Comment: See step 1. `<input type="hidden" name="from" value="the_about_page">`. You can simplify it by using URLs (just make sure that you check the URLs are on your own site and special case things like 'the login page' since showing that in response to the user logging in is silly).